# Is there a better solution to partition a hash into two hashes?

Tags: ruby

I wrote a method to split a hash into two hashes based on a criteria (a particular hash value). My question is different from [another question on Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565510/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-partition-a-large-hash-into-n-smaller-hashes-in). Here is an example of what I expect:

```
h={
  :a => "FOO",
  :b => "FOO",
  :c => "BAR",
  :d => "BAR",
  :e => "FOO"
}

h_foo, h_bar = partition(h)
```

I need `h_foo` and `h_bar` to be like:

```
h_foo={
  :a => "FOO",
  :b => "FOO",
  :e => "FOO"
} 

h_bar={
  :c => "BAR",
  :d => "BAR"
}
```

My solution is:

```
def partition h
  h.group_by{|k,v| v=="FOO"}.values.collect{|ary| Hash[*ary.flatten]}
end
```

Is there a clever solution?

Comment: You should post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's [`Enumerable#partition`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition):

```
h.partition { |k, v| v == "FOO" }.map(&:to_h)
#=> [{:a=>"FOO", :b=>"FOO", :e=>"FOO"}, {:c=>"BAR", :d=>"BAR"}]
```

Or you could use [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) to avoid the intermediate arrays:

```
h.each_with_object([{}, {}]) { |(k, v), (h_foo, h_bar)|
  v == "FOO" ? h_foo[k] = v : h_bar[k] = v
}
#=> [{:a=>"FOO", :b=>"FOO", :e=>"FOO"}, {:c=>"BAR", :d=>"BAR"}]
```

Comment: which version of Ruby are you using ? I am using 2.0 and the first method (which I was also thinking of) does not work.

Comment: [`Array#to_h`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h) was introduced in Ruby 2.1, you can use `.map { |a| Hash[a] }` instead.

Comment: Please note that the partition (+map+to_h) method is likely to produce reverted array result w.r.t 'my' partition() method. That is easily fixed.

Comment: I created a reproducer here https://gist.github.com/natelljahns/e8caba9559683de9a885

Comment: @JCLL your `group_by` method orders the output array depending on the input's first element. If the first element is a `Bar`, it returns `[bar_hash, foo_hash]`. Furthermore it returns an array with a single hash if all values are the same, e.g. `[bar_hash]`. My `partition` method always returns `[foo_hash, bar_hash]`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use builtin `partition`, which is doing almost exactly what you are looking for?

```
h_foo, h_bar = h.partition { |key, value| value == 'FOO' }
```

The only downside is that you will get arrays instead of hashes (but you already know how to convert that). In ruby 2.1+ you could simply call `.map(&:to_h)` at the end of call chain.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a clever one liner, but you can make it slightly more generic by doing something like:

```
def transpose(h,k,v)
  h[v] ||= []
  h[v] << k
end

def partition(h)
  n = {}
  h.map{|k,v| transpose(n,k,v)}
  result = n.map{|k,v| Hash[v.map{|e| [e, k]}] }
end
```

which will yield

```
[{:a=>"FOO", :b=>"FOO", :e=>"FOO"}, {:c=>"BAR", :d=>"BAR"}]
```

when run against your initial hash `h`

Edit - TIL about `partition`.  Wicked.